# nuget restore is unable to restore packages from local repository

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

## Restore from global nuget-repository

I have this packages.config-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.3.10" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

And with this command I can restore nuget-packages, which are listed in above packages.config:

> nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory NuGetPackages -NoCache

This works nicely.

All the files for this example can be found here: 
https://github.com/ezeh2/nuget_restore_examples/tree/master/nuget_with_global_nuget_repository

## Restore from local nuget-repository

In my company we have to use a repository, which is located on a network share.
And we are not allowed to do package restore from the standard global nuget-repository.

For demonstration-purposes let's assume the local package-repository is in directory `NuGetPackagesSource`
and this is its content:

```
-NuGetPackagesSource
 |-jquery
    |-3.1.1
      |-jquery.3.1.1.nupkg
      |-jquery.3.1.1.nupkg.sha512
      |-jquery.nuspec
 |-nlog.4.3.10.nupkg
```

With this NuGet.Config we make sure that the local package-repository is used instead of the global one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <packageSources>    
    <add key="my" value="NuGetPackagesSource" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Following makes a restore from local directory `NuGetPackagesSource`:

> nuget restore packages.config -ConfigFile NuGet.config -PackagesDirectory NuGetPackages -NoCache

Unfortunately following errors occur:

> WARNING: Unable to find version '3.1.1' of package 'jQuery'.
>    C:\software_download\nuget\NuGetPackagesSource: Package 'jQuery.3.1.1' is not found on source 'C:\software_download\nuget\NuGetPackagesSource'.
>
> Adding package 'NLog.4.3.10' to folder 'C:\software_download\nuget\NuGetPackages'
>   Added package 'NLog.4.3.10' to folder 'C:\software_download\nuget\NuGetPackages'
>
> Errors in packages.config projects
>      Unable to find version '3.1.1' of package 'jQuery'.
>        C:\software_download\nuget\NuGetPackagesSource: Package 'jQuery.3.1.1' is not found on source 'C:\software_download\nuget\NuGetPackagesSource'.

As you can see from the error-message package jquery cannot be restored. But package NLog is successfully restored. I have no explanation
of this behaviour as both packages `jquery` and `NLog` are in the local package-repository.

All the files for this example can be found here: 
https://github.com/ezeh2/nuget_restore_examples/tree/master/nuget_with_local_nuget_repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at your package repository. The `NLog`-package is directly underneath `NuGetPackagesSource`
whereas `jquery-package` is in path `jquery/3.1.1/jquery.3.1.1.nupkg`. You use a different folder structures for
packages `NLog` and `Jquery`. If **nuget** sees a nupkg-file directly underneath `NuGetPackagesSource` it assumes that
all nupkg-file are on the same level and it does not search in folders underneath `NuGetPackagesSource`. This
is why get error `Unable to find version '3.1.1' of package 'jQuery'`, even though `jquery`-package is there.

### How to fix this issue

Get rid of your `NuGetPackagesSource`-folder and build it newly from scratch with `nuget install` like this:

> nuget install `jQuery` -Version 3.3.1 -OutputDirectory NuGetPackagesSource
>
> nuget install `NLog` -Version 4.3.10 -OutputDirectory NuGetPackagesSource

### Alternative solution

Put all your nupkg-files directly under NuGetPackagesSource and don't use 
`nuget install` at all. But this only works for simple packages without additional folders. Unfortunately this cannot be done with `NLog` and `JQuery`.